# htaccess does not work on server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My htaccess rewrite works great in my local environment. However, it does not work on my 1&1 webspace.
Why is that? 

This is my .htaccess file

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I am really new to this and would be very thankful for any kind of help!

Comment: What does it do instead of work? Nothing at all? Do you have access to the `<VirtualHost>` config on 1and1? If so, does it include `AllowOverride All` (or any AllowOverride directive)? Without an `AllowOverride`, Apache won't even look for a .htaccess.

Comment: It throws a 404 error. How can I find out, if I have access to the <VirtualHost> config?

Comment: You would have to check with 1and1 support. And they might have documentation on how to setup .htaccess on their hosting offering.  Your .htaccess in and of itself would work fine as long as the server is setup to parse it and you actually have an index.php.

Comment: Great! Thank you! That is already very helpful for me!